# Why do I need to specify self when registering a UITableViewCell for a tableview in the register method?

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm looking to get a better understanding of why self needs to be called on the UITableViewCell type in this method for it to compile.

```
ableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the [signature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register) of the `.register` method is asking you to pass the cell class as a parameter?

```
func register(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

Or, were you wondering, why is the signature of the `.register` method such in the first place?

If that is the case, you can't just simply pass Type as a function argument, the function argument has to be some value.

Comment: It was the signature argument. That helped me understand. Thank you. So if I understand correctly .self allows to access the type as a value in run time. I see where the the Swift documentation refers to it as a metatype.